# Finding percentage of a dollar amount

Tags: percentages

I'm working with a website that can be used to pay contractors on my behalf, instead of requiring them to submit to me their W9 for taxes. The website takes $2.75\%$  in processing fees.

If I'm paying someone $\$22$ per hour, and the website requires $2.75\%$, I believe that would be $\$0.60$ of each hour that would be paid to the website.

That would mean if I still wanted to pay the developer $\$22$/hr including the fees, I would effectively be paying him $\$21.40$ per hour.

My problem is with checking my math. I was trying to figure out how to take the $\$21.40$ and multiply it some value to reach the $\$22$, but I don't know how to do that.

What value times $\$21.40$ equals $\$22$?

[I also could not figure out why the dollar sign caused the post to lose its formatting so surrounded it in preformatted tags.]

Comment: For formatting:  if you want to display a dollar sign you need to put a  backslash in front of it.  As to the question...what's wrong with taking $\frac {22}{21.4}\sim 1.028$?

Comment: Note:  I reformatted your question.  If you click on 'edit' you can see the syntax I used to display the dollar sign and the percent sign.

Comment: As you see from the posted solutions, there is some confusion as to your question.  Both solutions posit that you are asking "what nominal wage should I pay if I want my contractor to receive $\$22$ per hour?".  That is a sensible question, but it isn't what you actually ask.  Indeed, you ask "what value times $\$21.40$ equals $\$22$?" which is a different question.  Perhaps you could clarify which one you intended to ask?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. I really meant this to be an academic question. I intended to ask:

If \$22 - (\$22/hr * 2.75%) = \$21.40, how do I go the other way around? In other words, if I was given that the rate after the 2.75% was applied was \$21.40, how do I get back to the \$22/hr?

I'd also of course like to confirm that if I want to pay the developer \$22/hr including fees, his hourly rate would indeed be \$21.40/hr.

Comment: Ok.  So...let $X$ be the nominal wage.  We know that $X-.0275X = 21.4$ .  But $X-.0275X = .9725X$ so we have $.9725X = 21.4\implies X=\frac {21.4}{.9725}\sim 22.00514139$.  That's your $\$22$.  The slight difference comes from the fact that you rounded initially ($22-.0275\times 22=.9725\times 22=21.395$ which you rounded to $21.4$).

Comment: Somehow the formatting for all of the responses as well as my initial question have been stripped away, instead showing only the raw format characters :-( For example, your response includes "X=\frac {21.4}{.9725}\sim" and not the formatted version.

Answer (score 1):

If the processing fee is $2.75\%$ of the amount processed, and you want to have $\$22$ after the fee is taken out, then you have the following equation:
$$x-x\times2.75\%=22,$$
where $x$ is the initial amount (i.e. before the processing fee is taken).

Read the equation as:

1. **From** the initial amount $x$
2. **take out** $2.75\%$ **of** the initial amount $x$,
3. and that should be **equal** to $22$.

[Factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization) of the left-hand side (further referred to as LHS) gives
$$x\left(1-2.75\%\right)=22$$
(multiply out to check); then notice that [a percent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization) is exactly one hundredth of the unity:
$$x\left(1-2.75\frac1{100}\right)=22;$$
now rewrite the unity as $100/100$ and multiply the $2.75$ by the fraction, which in this case just moves $2.75$ into the numerator:
$$x\left(\frac{100}{100}-\frac{2.75}{100}\right)=22;$$
denominators are now equal, so we can bring the numerators over one fraction bar:
$$x\left(\frac{100-2.75}{100}\right)=22;$$
perform the subtraction in the numerator:
$$x\frac{97.25}{100}=22;$$
divide both sides by the fraction:
$$x\frac{97.25}{100}/\frac{97.25}{100}=22/\frac{97.25}{100};$$
that gets rid of the fraction on the LHS:
$$x=22/\frac{97.25}{100};$$
division by a fraction is equivalent to multiplication by the same fraction but with numerator and denominator swapped:
$$x=22\frac{100}{97.25};$$
multiply the integer $22$ by the fraction, which brings it into the numerator as a multiple:
$$x=\frac{22\times100}{97.25};$$
perform the multiplication:
$$x=\frac{2200}{97.25};$$
we arrived at the desired answer; the fraction may be further simplified, or a decimal approximation up to four decimals after the decimal point may be obtain by division on a calculator:
$$x\approx22.6221;$$
round the value **up** (need to explain why?), which gives

### $$22\text{ dollars and }63\text{ cents.}$$

P. S. Notice that this StackExchange site employs [MathJax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization) to enable $\LaTeX$ typesetting of mathematical formulae. For a basic tutorial and reference on the language, [please refer to this link](http://mathjax.org/).